# Как правильно использовать CoordinatorLayout с GridView в Android?

Tags: android

Мне нужно сделать палакс эффект Toolbar*a* при прокрутке моего GridView.

Делал все по примерах взятых из интернета. Сейчас код выглядит так.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

Результат такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мало того что GridView превратился в ListView, так ещё и ToolBar при прокрутке не уменьшается.

Если у кого есть нормальные гайды по CoordinatorLayout, скидывайте.

Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте RecyclerView + GridLayoutManager и будет вам счастье. На сколько я знаю, CoordinatorLayout и прочие новомодные штуки работают с ограниченным количеством вьюх из коробки.
Чтобы найти хороший тутор, стоит просто погуглить и все найдете.